# Import error in iPython after installing umfpack

Tags: python-2.7, importerror

After installing the umfpack package (which I needed) I can no longer import any packages in an iPython Notebook. Any import command e.g

```
import numpy as np
```

results in a stream of errors the last of which is

```
/Users/murray/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py in <module>()
 12         os.environ[envkey] = '1'
 13         env_added.append(envkey)
---> 14 from . import multiarray
 15 for envkey in env_added:
 16     del os.environ[envkey]

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/murray/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libopenblas-r0.2.18.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/murray/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so
Reason: image not found
```

I'm really out of my depth herem so if you can help, assume I am a total novice.

Answer (score 1):

Someone fixed it for me by reinstalling everything.