# numpy image not found when importing gensim in python 3.7

Tags: numpy, scipy, anaconda, gensim

When using gensim utils to preprocess text for NLP, the library makes a call to numpy and returns (inter alia) this error message

```
IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
Here is how to proceed:
- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
- If you are simply trying to use the numpy version that you have installed:
  your installation is broken - please reinstall numpy.
- If you have already reinstalled and that did not fix the problem, then:
  1. Check that you are using the Python you expect (you're using /Users/lorajohns/anaconda3/bin/python),
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy versions you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

     Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
     an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: dlopen(/Users/$(USER)/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libopenblas.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/$(USER)/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I already tried fixing the path and my .bash profile, in case it was a case of competing python installations. I am using venvs, so I also uninstalled any additional virtual env extensions that could potentially cause a conflict (pyenv). I reinstalled all packages into a new `conda` env, and updated `conda` and `anaconda`.

Essentially, I followed all the instructions, and nothing succeeded.

Comment: Have you tried running it in an `env` with a different python version? afaik, gensim is only "officially" supported for 3.6.8., not above (yet).

Answer (score 1):

It does seem similar to the issue described here: [Import error in iPython after installing umfpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42776766/import-error-in-ipython-after-installing-umfpack)

Are you sure you do not have `umfpack` installed as well? Have you tried an install from scratch?